# Knockout component using jQuery-ui dialog ignores bindings

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using knockout components to modularize my UI.
One of them instances a jQuery-ui dialog containing few buttons.
All data-bind on them, and on anything contained in the dialog, is simply ignored.
Yes, I have read the warnings here against mixing knockout and jQuery, but which alternatives have I?
Well, in this simple case I have a workaround. Keep reading.

My component is split into `test.html`

```
<div id="trashcan-dlg">
    <button data-bind="click: trashcanRecoverAll">Recover all</button>
</div>
```

and `test.js`

```
"use strict";

define(["jquery", "jquery-ui"], function($) {

    function TrashcanWidgetViewModel(params) {

        $("#trashcan-dlg")
            .dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: "auto",
                width: "auto",
                modal: false,
                title: "Trashcan management"
            });
    }

    TrashcanWidgetViewModel.prototype.trashcanRecoverAll = function() {
        console.log("trashcanRecoverAll");
    };

    return TrashcanWidgetViewModel;
});
```

registered with:

```
ko.components.register("test", {
    viewModel: {require: "widgets/test"},
    template:  {require: "text!widgets/test.html"}
});
```

The problem does not change if I define a custom binding for the dialog. No error, nothing. If jQuery-ui dialog rewrites the DOM, this makes sense: there are no `data-bind` directives in the resulting DOM. Or I'm missing something obvious?

In this simple case the workaround is to get rid of the `click` binding and use non-ko click event handling. Just add the following to the constructor:

```
this.toolbarTrashcan = function() {
    console.log("trashcanPurgeSelected");
};
$("button", "#trashcan-dlg").on("click", this.toolbarTrashcan);
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Currently trying http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/ that seems solved the problem (at least in the online demo) but without success. It fails saying that in jQuery.ui.core Cannot read property 'core' of undefined. Sigh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem is that you make this call `$("#trashcan-dlg").dialog(...)` before the component instantiating is complete.
Your `click` binding should start woring if you change that part of code to:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#trashcan-dlg")
        .dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto",
            modal: false,
            title: "Trashcan management"
        });
}, 0);
```

setTimeout(...) would put $("#trashcan-dlg").dialog(...) call to the end of JS event loop so it would be executed when `ko` infrastructure has completed with DOM manipulations.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem. The only non essential modification I made was to change `setTimeout()` into `ko.tasks.schedule()`